# Download a package with rosmake

Tags: ros, rosdep, download, manifest.xml, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I created a stack which includes one teleop package. this package uses the library Qt and depends on the stack eros to build it.
In the current state, before building my package, I need to install the eros stack by following the installation instruction: http://www.ros.org/wiki/eros/Installation

I included the necessary eros_build package as a depend in my manifest.xml, but that doesn't download and install this package or even the eros stack.

My question would be, is there a way to automatize the download of the eros stack while executing rosmake in my package, if the stack wasn't found?

Thank you for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12466/download-a-package-with-rosmake/) by [MorganCormier](https://answers.ros.org/users/360/morgancormier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2011-12-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosmake is not designed to download and build packages.  It only does the building part.

I suggest that you look at using [rosinstall](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosinstall) to install your packages.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MorganCormier](https://answers.ros.org/users/360/morgancormier/) on 2011-12-27**:
Thanks for your help, I looked into that and it is very easy to use.